# Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am not able to receive fcm through app server for topic messages in fcm.
The topic I have subscribed to is showing in the Firebase Console.
When i am trying to send requests ,response is coming by the tag:message_id
but the fcm message is not coming on the device.
I tried the demo of androidhive, in that also when send through single device is 
selected the fcm pops up on the device but the topic message is not sent on device.

```
<?php class Firebase { public function sendToTopic($to, $message) {
    $fields = array(
        'to' => '/topics/' . $to,
        'data' => $message,
    );
    return $this->sendPushNotification($fields);
}



// function makes curl request to firebase servers
private function sendPushNotification($fields) {

    require_once  'config.php';

    // Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . FIREBASE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```

}
?>

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Firebase Cloud Messaging</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//www.gstatic.com/mobilesdk/160503_mobilesdk/logo/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css">

    <style type="text/css">
        body{
        }
        div.container{
            width: 1000px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: relative;
        }
        legend{
            font-size: 30px;
            color: #555;
        }
        .btn_send{
            background: #00bcd4;
        }
        label{
            margin:10px 0px !important;
        }
        textarea{
            resize: none !important;
        }
        .fl_window{
            width: 400px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top:100px;
        }
        pre, code {
            padding:10px 0px;
            box-sizing:border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
            webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
            display:block; 
            white-space: pre-wrap;  
            white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; 
            white-space: -pre-wrap; 
            white-space: -o-pre-wrap; 
            word-wrap: break-word; 
            width:100%; overflow-x:auto;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    // Enabling error reporting
    error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

    require_once 'firebase.php';
    require_once 'push.php';

    $firebase = new Firebase();
    $push = new Push();



    // notification title
    $title = isset($_GET['title']) ? $_GET['title'] : '';

    // notification message
    $message = isset($_GET['message']) ? $_GET['message'] : '';

    // push type - single user / topic
    $push_type = isset($_GET['push_type']) ? $_GET['push_type'] : '';

    // whether to include to image or not
    $include_image = isset($_GET['include_image']) ? TRUE : FALSE;


    $push->setTitle($title);
    $push->setMessage($message);
    if ($include_image) {
        $push->setImage('https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/localcircles-s/circleimages/09092015/178681857255efc93313ad9_male_09092015112251_profile.jpg');
    } else {
        $push->setImage('');
    }
    $push->setIsBackground(FALSE);



    $json = '';
    $response = '';

    if ($push_type == 'topic') {
        $json = $push->getPush();
        $response = $firebase->sendToTopic('offers', $json);
    } 
    ?>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="fl_window">
            <div><img src="http://api.androidhive.info/images/firebase_logo.png" width="200" alt="Firebase"/></div>
            <br/>
            <?php if ($json != '') { ?>
                <label><b>Request:</b></label>
                <div class="json_preview">
                    <pre><?php echo json_encode($json) ?></pre>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <br/>
            <?php if ($response != '') { ?>
                <label><b>Response:</b></label>
                <div class="json_preview">
                    <pre><?php echo json_encode($response) ?></pre>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>

        </div>


        <br/><br/><br/><br/>

        <form class="pure-form pure-form-stacked" method="get">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Send to Topic `offers`</legend>

                <label for="title1">Title</label>
                <input type="text" id="title1" name="title" class="pure-input-1-2" placeholder="Enter title">

                <label for="message1">Message</label>
                <textarea class="pure-input-1-2" name="message" id="message1" rows="5" placeholder="Notification message!"></textarea>

                <label for="include_image1" class="pure-checkbox">
                    <input id="include_image1" name="include_image" type="checkbox"> Include image
                </label>
                <input type="hidden" name="push_type" value="topic"/>
                <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary btn_send">Send to Topic</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Add extra details about your classes,firebase services and etc..

Comment: SIR,i have tried the demo of androidhive,this is the link http://demo.androidhive.info/firebase/notifications/

Comment: please post some code what you have implemented already from that url

Comment: Sir, i have posted it.Please help.

Comment: that url is external developer developed to support FCM. check android docs see this URL https://console.firebase.google.com/

Comment: Sorry Sir,  but what i have to change?